Plot AG Grid Detail data in AG Chart instead of Master detail
I have built a nested grid using AG Grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/master-detail-nesting/). I have also intergraded AG Charts, including 2 pie charts and a bar chart. A sample of the data loaded into the AG Grid is as follows:
[
  {
    "subCategory": "Manufacturers Name 1",
    "discount": 100,
    "amount": 60, 
    "products": [
      {
        "sku": "AUC5975",
        "description": "stainless steel toaster",
        "ASP": "£7.48",
        "CostPrice": 31.79,
        "CurrentPrice": 28.60,
        "CategoryPrice": 435.74,
        "SubCategoryPrice": 1158.17,
        "Margin": 57
      },
      {
        "sku": "GTG2761",
        "description": "white microwave oven",
        "ASP": "£071.39",
        "CostPrice": 64.16,
        "CurrentPrice": 541.44,
        "CategoryPrice": 915.74,
        "SubCategoryPrice": 70.46,
        "Margin": 28
      }
    ]
  }
]

Currently the charts are populated using the Master top-level data, hence display data columns fields such as 'subCategory', 'discount', 'amount', which all works fine. However, I would like to plot the Detail sub-level data in the charts instead, hence sub-data columns fields such as 'sku', 'CostPrice' and 'CurrentPrice'. Ive looked at the documentation, but I cannot find an example that does this.

Code:
**import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "@ag-grid-community/react";
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css";
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import {
  ChartToolPanelsDef,
  ColDef,
  FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  GridReadyEvent,
  IDetailCellRendererParams,
  ModuleRegistry,
} from "@ag-grid-community/core";
import { ColumnsToolPanelModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel";
import { MasterDetailModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail";
import { MenuModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu";
import { IProduct, ISubCategory } from "./interfaces";
import { GridChartsModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/charts-enterprise";
import { RowGroupingModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping";

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
  ClientSideRowModelModule,
  ColumnsToolPanelModule,
  MasterDetailModule,
  MenuModule,
  RowGroupingModule,
  GridChartsModule,
]);

function createGroupedBarChart(
  params: FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  selector: string,
  columns: string[]
) {
  params.api.createRangeChart({
    chartContainer: document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement,
    cellRange: {
      rowStartIndex: 0,
      rowEndIndex: 4,
      columns,
    },
    suppressChartRanges: true,
    chartType: "groupedBar",
  });
}

function createPieChart(
  params: FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  selector: string,
  columns: string[]
) {
  params.api.createRangeChart({
    chartContainer: document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement,
    cellRange: { columns },
    suppressChartRanges: true,
    chartType: "pie",
    aggFunc: "sum",
    chartThemeOverrides: {
      common: {
        legend: {
          position: "right",
        },
      },
    },
  });
}

export const GridExampleNest = () => {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({ width: "100%", height: "500px" }),
    []
  );
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: "100%", width: "100%" }), []);

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<ISubCategory[]>();
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    {
      field: "subCategory",
      cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
      chartDataType: "category",
    },
    { field: "amount", chartDataType: "series", editable: true, valueFormatter: "'£' + x" },
    { field: "discount", chartDataType: "series", editable: true, valueFormatter: "x + '%'" },
  ]);

  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
    };
  }, []);

  const chartToolPanelsDef = useMemo<ChartToolPanelsDef>(() => {
    return { panels: [] };
  }, []);
  const popupParent = useMemo<HTMLElement | null>(() => {
    return document.body;
  }, []);
  const getChartToolbarItems = useCallback(() => [], []);

  const detailCellRendererParams = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      detailGridOptions: {
        paginationPageSize: 100,
        pagination: true,
        rowHeight: 25,
        headerHeight: 25,
        columnDefs: [
          { field: "sku", minWidth: 150 },
          { field: "description", minWidth: 200, chartDataType: "category", },
          { field: "TwelveWeekSales", minWidth: 150 },
          { field: "ASP", minWidth: 100 },
          { field: "CostPrice", minWidth: 150, chartDataType: "series", valueFormatter: "'£' + x" },
          { field: "CurrentPrice", minWidth: 150, editable: true, chartDataType: "series", valueFormatter: "'£' + x"  },
        ] as ColDef[],
        defaultColDef: {
          flex: 1,
        },
      },
      getDetailRowData: (params: any) => {
        params.successCallback(params.data.products);
      },
    } as unknown as IDetailCellRendererParams<ISubCategory, IProduct>;
  }, []);

  const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    fetch("dataNest.json")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data: ISubCategory[]) => {
        // params.api.setGridOption("rowData", data);
        setRowData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0)!.setExpanded(true);
      createGroupedBarChart(params, "#chart1", [
        "subCategory",
        "amount",
        "discount",
      ]);
      createPieChart(params, "#chart2", ["subCategory", "amount"]);
      createPieChart(params, "#chart3", ["subCategory", "discount"]);
    }, 0);
  }, []);

  const handleOnCellEditingStopped = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  const pagination = true;
  const paginationPageSize = 10;
  const paginationPageSizeSelector = [10, 20, 50, 100];

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flex: "1 1 auto",
          height: "30%",
          gap: "8px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          id="chart1"
          className="my-chart"
          style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", width: "33%", height: "100" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          id="chart2"
          className="pie-chart-1"
          style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", width: "33%" }}
        ></div>
        <div
          id="chart3"
          className="pie-chart-2"
          style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", width: "33%" }}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div style={gridStyle} className={"ag-theme-quartz"}>
        <AgGridReact<ISubCategory>
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          cellSelection={true}
          masterDetail={true}
          detailCellRendererParams={detailCellRendererParams}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          onCellEditingStopped={(e) => handleOnCellEditingStopped(e)}
          onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
          pagination={pagination}
          paginationPageSize={paginationPageSize}
          paginationPageSizeSelector={paginationPageSizeSelector}
          enableCharts={true}
          chartToolPanelsDef={chartToolPanelsDef}
          popupParent={popupParent}
          getChartToolbarItems={getChartToolbarItems}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};**

